# When we need to use $digest() in real development?

Tags: angularjs

I don't understand for what people use angular $digest().
Could you give me any simple examples please?

Comment: You shouldn't use $digest() in production code. It can be necessary (although calling $apply() has the same effect) when unit-testing directives, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `$digest()` triggers the digest cycle (eval watchers and render view) in Angular. You should avoid calling this by yourself, prefer `$applyAsync()` instead. This can be useful when you update some data aynchronously and want to notice Angular about these changes.

For a good explanation, I'd suggest this blog post:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a callback attached to an event that is outside of angular's scope; angular has no idea when that function runs/ends so the digest cycle is never ran. (for example mouseevents in a directive)

```
app.directive('tooltip',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind('mouseover',function(e){

                scope.setStyle(e);

            });
        }
    }
});


$scope.setStyle = function(e){
    $scope.style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        // some other styles
    };

    $scope.$apply();
};
```

**Calling $digest or $apply tells angular to update bindings and fire any watches.**

I hope it helps.